# JavaScript Onclick phone/email validation function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have one search field, where I want users to be able to search by either phone or email. However, my onclick event does not fire. I've tried the console tools, but can't seem to debug through there.

```
<body>  

</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method="POST"  action="/">
        <dl style="display:inline-block">{{render_field(form.search)}}</dl> 
        <button id="searchbutton" style="display:inline-block" type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="doValidate()" >Search</button>

    </form>
</div>  

<script>

function validateEmail(email) { //Validates the email address
    var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return emailRegex.test(email);
}

function validatePhone(phone) { //Validates the phone number
    var phoneRegex = /^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/; // Change this regex based on requirement
    return phoneRegex.test(phone);
}

function doValidate() {
   if (!validateEmail(document.appointment.requiredphone.value) || !validatePhone(document.appointment.requiredphone.value) ){
    alert("Invalid Email");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: "Can't seem to debug through there".  That should be the _first_ thing that you resolve, so that you can successfully debug your projects.  What doesn't work about the console? Also - please show the _rendered HTML_, not the template language.  Finally, you really should provide an [mcve] for the best help.

Comment: How are you determining the `onclick` event is not firing? The lack of an alert? Because that could have to do with many other things. Put the alert before the `if`. Also, you just use HTML's `pattern` attribute instead of JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script works in concept, however since you didn't include the rendered markup, and are potentially not including some of the relevant javascript, it's difficult to identify the specific issue you are having.

The issue is almost certainly related to this javascript from your code:

```
document.appointment.requiredphone.value
```

What is `appointment`? What is `requiredphone`? Without knowing how the HTML is structured, it's impossible to identify the *exact* problem.

Because you only included `{{render_field(form.search)}}` instead of the *rendered HTML*, this is as far as we can help.

**Working Snippet**
(using `document.getElementById`, and some text inputs)

```js
function validateEmail(email) { //Validates the email address
  var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return emailRegex.test(email);
}

function validatePhone(phone) { //Validates the phone number
  var phoneRegex = /^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/; // Change this regex based on requirement
  return phoneRegex.test(phone);
}

function doValidate() {
  if (!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value) || !validatePhone(document.getElementById('password').value)) {
    alert("Invalid Email");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form method="POST" action="/">
    <dl style="display:inline-block"><input type="text" id="email"><input type="text" id="password"></dl>
    <button id="searchbutton" style="display:inline-block" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="doValidate()">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You.... one other thing... is it possible to validate either phone or email from one text (html) field instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be the `form` submitting when you click the button.
Try event.preventDefault() to prevent form submit action

```
<button id="searchbutton" style="display:inline-block" type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="doValidate(event)" >Search</button>

function doValidate(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // pass from button
   console.log('here');
   if (!validateEmail(document.appointment.requiredphone.value) || !validatePhone(document.appointment.requiredphone.value) ){
    alert("Invalid Email");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you do a console.log('here'); inside doValidate() below the e.preventDefault to see if the function is executing ?

Comment: "did not work" is not a clear problem statement.  What is / is not happening?